# Router address and IP keep changing

Tags: mac, router, ip-address

my router was originally 192.168.1.1, but recently the DHCP is assigning it to 24.230.166.1.  When I enter in a manual IP and router number, I can type in 192.168.1.1 into safari and access my router settings, but can't get on actual sites.  My internet isn't very reliable and is hard connecting with different computers.  I have a linksys router connecting to a macbook pro; just wondering if I should update the firmware or what the problem is.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to check with your Internet Service Provider, as they are the one passing the connection to you.  They can change the WAN IP--it happens more than you think.

For now, were you able to get to the internet when it had the 24.230.166.1 address?  If so, change it back to that, or leave the WAN on DHCP Client Mode.

Comment: Yes I am able to get on the internet, but ever few days it will switch back to the 192.168.1.1 router and the internet won't work. My internet providers are clueless and just tell me it's something wrong with my computer. Everytime my internet stops working I have to use ethernet to get into my router settings and refresh the wireless internet security.

Answer (score 0):

There is another device on your network that is running a DHCP server, and from time to time, when you request an IP address, this device is answering first, and giving you an IP in the 24.230.166.0 range.

The device is at 24.230.166.1 from your description, so it should be relatively easy to track down and disable the dhcp server.

Comment: Even when i connect using ethernet its still giving the 24.230.166.0 ip. My wifi has actually stopped working completely and the DHCP won't even assign an IP address, it's just blank. Occasionally it will assign the 169.xxx.x.x but that's just the local address and won't give me internet.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your cable modem's Ethernet cable is plugged into the port marked "WAN" or "Internet" on the Linksys router. If it's plugged into any other port, you will experience problems like the ones you've described.